# Tortoise Git change the last commit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Im trying to change the last commit message by the tortoise git. I found the following answer on this forum:
If the commit is the head of current branch, that is easy.

1. Context menu -> Git Commit
2. Tick "Amend Last Commit" checkbox
3. Correct your commit message
4. OK

But Im not able to find the "Amend Last Commit" checkbox. Please help

Answer (score 1):

After you did "TortoiseGit" → "Commit..."

[image: TortoiseGit commit dialog]

Answer (score 0):

I could found it finally, that I had to do git commit again . In the commit window I could see the tick box.
Thanks a lot Reynadan for answering, but I found it yesterday just after posting !